# How to format the date in HTML in dd-MM-YYYY format using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I would like to format the date in HTML as dd-mm-yyyy format in ng-model but the result which I am getting is in the form of mm-dd-yyyy.I have tried using interpolator where it worked fine and I would like to know to get the output in a dd-mm-yyyy format in HTML itself using ng-model.

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <input placeholder="Date" type="date" date="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="vm.advance.date"></input>
</label>
```

Comment: I presume you are using a standard HTML input control, so the date format for standard control comes from local Systems datetime format. As a solution you can watch the scope model and use an angular inbuilt filter to format date.

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('MyController', function() {  
    this.advance = {
       date: new Date()
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>    
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">  
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input ng-model="vm.advance.date" ng-value="vm.advance.date | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'" ng-disabled="true"/>
    </label>   
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="vm.opened" ng-model="vm.advance.date" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-required="true" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.opened = true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Slavac Utesinov then how to add a datepicker along with the input

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript way of doing this** using $filter, but the type would be of string not the Date even if you use html or js way of filter ('|' pipe)

```js
angular.module('inputExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope,$filter) {
     $scope.advance = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
   }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="inputExample">

<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input placeholder="Date" ng-model="advance"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to use value with filter:

```
{{vm.advance.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Actual better to use datepicker for it. There is more flexiable tools for it.

Comment: Bucka i have already tried with the above solution but i want it in ng-model

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below example.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.firstDate = new Date();
    $scope.secondDate = "2014-02-20";
})


// Here is where the magic works
.directive('date', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            var dateFormat = attrs['date'] || 'yyyy-MM-dd';

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, dateFormat);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/banshilaldangi/pen/zZmayM)**